# Counting conditional matches in SQL

Tags: sql, select, join

**Problem:**

Find the number of matching records in the Person table where First and last names are the same, or, the SSN is the same.

***GIVENS***

**TABLE STRUCTURE:** Person

```
FirstName
LastName
SSN
RecordId
```

**DATA:** in Person table

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║     SSN     ║ RECORDID ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║ Bob       ║ Smith    ║ 111-11-1111 ║        1 ║
║ Robert    ║ Smyth    ║ 111-11-1111 ║        2 ║
║ Bob       ║ Smith    ║ 222-22-2222 ║        3 ║
║ Tom       ║ Gunn     ║ 333-33-3333 ║        4 ║
║ Jim       ║ Gunn     ║ 444-44-4444 ║        5 ║
║ Jimmy     ║ Gunn     ║ 444-44-4444 ║        6 ║
║ Alice     ║ Jones    ║ 555-55-5555 ║        7 ║
║ Alice     ║ Jones    ║ 666-66-6666 ║        8 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

**DESIRED RESULTS:**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ MATCHCOUNT ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║     SSN     ║ RECORDID ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║          3 ║ Bob       ║ Smith    ║ 111-11-1111 ║        1 ║
║          2 ║ Robert    ║ Smyth    ║ 111-11-1111 ║        2 ║
║          2 ║ Bob       ║ Smith    ║ 222-22-2222 ║        3 ║
║          1 ║ Tom       ║ Gunn     ║ 333-33-3333 ║        4 ║
║          2 ║ Jim       ║ Gunn     ║ 444-44-4444 ║        5 ║
║          2 ║ Jimmy     ║ Gunn     ║ 444-44-4444 ║        6 ║
║          2 ║ Alice     ║ Jones    ║ 555-55-5555 ║        7 ║
║          2 ║ Alice     ║ Jones    ║ 666-66-6666 ║        8 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried using both GROUP BY  and an LEFT self JOIN to solve this problem.

GROUP BY fails because there is no way to conditionally group.

The LEFT self JOIN fails because it returns roughly the square of the number of matches.

I would post the code of my attempts, but my real tables have a large number of columns and  is actually far more complex and would almost certainly obscure the issue.

Comment: Sounds like homework. Update your question with [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) and I will remove the downvote.

Comment: When you reduce a problem to the essentials, it can often look like homework.  I suggest you might be a little less cavalier with your down votes.

Comment: Sorry you didn't like my downvote. I expect questions to show effort, not give code and expect it to be solved. I would recommend reading  [Jon Skeet's guide](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you haven't mentioned RDBMS, try this,

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) MatchCount,a.*
FROM    person a
        INNER JOIN person b
            ON  (a.firstname = b.firstname AND
                    a.lastname = b.lastname) OR
                    a.SSN = b.SSn
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, ssn, recordid
ORDER By recordid
```

**Result**

```
| MATCHCOUNT | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME |         SSN | RECORDID |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|          3 |       Bob |    Smith | 111-11-1111 |        1 |
|          2 |    Robert |    Smyth | 111-11-1111 |        2 |
|          2 |       Bob |    Smith | 222-22-2222 |        3 |
|          1 |       Tom |     Gunn | 333-33-3333 |        4 |
|          2 |       Jim |     Gunn | 444-44-4444 |        5 |
|          2 |     Jimmy |     Gunn | 444-44-4444 |        6 |
|          2 |     Alice |    Jones | 555-55-5555 |        7 |
|          2 |     Alice |    Jones | 666-66-6666 |        8 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8295e/2)

Comment: Well @#$$^, I am impressed with such a quick answer.  I was doing something very similar, but there must be some mistake in my logic.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JW.Your answer helped me solve my problem.  I had not thought to include the unique record id in the GROUP BY clause.  Thanks again.